# Button click in Android Fragment does not work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name="sithi.test.fragmenttest.Fragment1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:onClick="btnClick1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**ActivityMain.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

**Fragment1.java**

```
 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
 public class Fragment1 extends Fragment
 {
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    public void onStart() 
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    tv=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //inflater.inflate(resource, root, attachToRoot);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
    }

    public void btnClick1(View view)
    {
    tv.setText("dsdsdasda");
    }


   }
```

I created xml files and classes like this but `btnClick1()` does not work in Android Fragment.
It will getting an error when i clicking that button in the fragment. I have written that button click function inside the Fragment class.

Comment: 05-08 12:44:43.156: W/dalvikvm(29123): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40aa6210)
05-08 12:44:43.436: E/AndroidRuntime(29123): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-08 12:44:43.436: E/AndroidRuntime(29123): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method btnClick1(View) in the activity class sithi.test.fragmenttest.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button1'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way XML onClick is implemented is directed to Activities, not Fragments. The activity should own the `btnClick1` method, not a fragment.

Comment: so how can we implement an onclickListener in fragments??

Comment: Can I know how to getting out that btnClick1 event from Activity. Is there any option to do it?

Comment: The favored way is using a listener programmatically. The xml way is just used for toys apps. myButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() { void onClicked(View v) {//yourcode here}});

Comment: @Snicolas Thank you, this comment is just what I was looking for, because I was wondering how do I get fragments conponents to set their values. And even if there was a way, this wouldn't seem right to me!

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign OnClickListener in fragment code to make it work. See Snicolas answer for the "why".

Comment: I overided the onStart() method and assigned OnClickListener in onStart() method. It Worked fine.

Comment: @user2361252 `onCreateView` or `onViewCreated` might be a better place for that.

Answer (score 0):

Since others have addressed setting onClick listener, let me add that if you have done so, and still getting the error check permissions required. For my case, the item on fragment was meant to open chat which requires microphone so it was not working until I added appropriate permissions in Manifest file.