# How to make clickable layout in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Here is my java code of a swipe fragment and i have made a layout inside that fragment,
I want to make "ongoing" RelativeLayout to clickable for navigating to other activity.
Please help me to sort out the issue.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import info.androidhive.CrescentBuilders.R;

public class Ongoing extends Fragment {
  @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
              Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ongoing_frag, container, false);
          //((TextView)android.findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("Ongoing Projects");
          RelativeLayout ongoing=(RelativeLayout)android.findViewById(R.id.layoutongoing);
           return android;



}


}
```

Comment: Clear your question first???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Button click in Android Fragment does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435122/button-click-in-android-fragment-does-not-work)

Comment: Implement `onClickListener` method for `RelativeLayout` .

Answer (score 1):

You should find Id in onViewCreated instead of onCreateView if layout is in your fragment

```
@Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ongoing_frag, container, false);

       return android;
   }

  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       RelativeLayout ongoing=(RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.layoutongoing);
   }
```